# Равнозначны ли методы объявления интерфейсов?

Tags: java

Можно ли объявление интерфейса `list` таким образом:

```
ArrayList<Customer> array_list = new ArrayList<>();

List<Customer> list = new ArrayList<>(array_list);
```

заменить на объявление в одну строчку таким образом?

```
List<Customer> list2 = new ArrayList<Customer>();
```

Пытаюсь разобраться в этом вопросе, но немного недопонимаю. Излагаю ход своих мыслей:

1. При объявлении интерфейса (будь то `List` или `ArrayList`) в угловых скобках `<>` указывается `тип интерфейса`.
2. Тогда что указывается в круглых скобках `()` при объявлении интерфейса `new ArrayList<>(array_list)`? Из кода понятно, что это `имя интерфейса`.

**Вопрос 1** - как это работает?

**Вопрос 2** - возможно ли заменить, как указано выше, объявление интерфейса `list` объявлением интерфейса `list2`, только в одну строчку?

Comment: интерфейс не создается, создается реализация. в скобках передается содержимое вновь создаваемого списка.

Comment: @StrangerintheQ сейчас исправлю это в вопросе

Comment: Можно, а вообще, советую сначала пробовать, прежде, чем задавать вопрос. А круглые скобки, это конструктор класса. Когда создаете объект, можно вызывать разные конструкторы, с помощью прототипа `(,,,,)` где перечисляются аргументы, определенных конструкторов, по умолчанию конструктор без аргументов и можно не писать.

Comment: Вопрос задал с точки зрения правильности реализации. Увидел в примере чужого кода объявление интерфейса в две строки. Правильно ли объявлять интерфейс в одну строчку, как написал я? Если правильно, как ответили Вы, @And, то какой смысл от объявления в две строки?

Comment: это `Полиморфизм`. Одна из особенностей языка, вы также сможете это применять и в наследовании других классов. То есть за место того, чтобы писать каждый тип класса, вы можете написать только класс родитель. `Parent variable = new Child();`, `Parent variable = new Child2();`. Также происходит и с `List`, `Map`, `Set` - это интерфейсы. То есть все враианты будут работать верно `Map<?,?> m1 = new TreeMap<>();`, `Map<?,?> m2 = new HashMap<>();`, `Map<?,?> m3 = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Первый вариант копирует список, а во втором список только один.

https://ideone.com/POSKDQ

```
import java.util.*;

class Ideone {
  public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    ArrayList<Integer> array_list = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(array_list);

    list.add(2);

    System.out.println(array_list.size() + " " + list.size());
  }
}
```

```
0 1
```

Comment: Ну и за что минус?

Answer (score 1):

```
1  List
2       <Customer> 
3                  list = new 
4                             ArrayList
5                                      <ConcreteCustomer>
6                                                         ();
```

1 - Контракт (конкретный класс или интерфейс) для переменной `list`

2 - Контракт для Generic типа для п.1.

В данном случае мы объявляем, что `list` будет реализовывать контракт `List` и элементы в нём содержащиеся будут реализовывать контракт `Customer`

3 - и так понятно

4 - Конкретный класс, реализующий контракт п.1.

5 - Аналогично п.2.

В данным случае мы объявляем, что `list` будет реализован как `ArrayList`, а элементы в нём будут `ConcreteCustomer`

6 - В скобочки можно запихнуть аргументы конструктора п.5.

Также в этом случае мы можем в п.5 использовать сокращенную запись `<>`

Comment: Это можно было просто объяснить как `ПОЛИМОРФИЗМ`, и не глобалить.

Comment: Судя по вопросу тут требовалось именно разложить на составляющие, а не ругаться страшным словом ;)

Comment: Тише @And, все в порядке. Рассмотрю любые варианты ответа. Не нужно никого минусовать. Расписал человек подробно - хорошо. Только вот для меня контрактное программирование, как термин и суть, ещё не известны. Поэтому может кому пригодится :)

Comment: @n199a контракт - это, по сути, то, чему объект обязуется соответствовать. Самый простой пример - интерфейс. Если, допустим, класс имплементит интерфейс `Animal`, то реализовать все его методы - это контракт, который он соблюдает.